# I can't find certain files on my android that should be there

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I've been trying to reach data/data/com.android.browser/webview.db after rooting my galaxy s4 but when I go to find this file I can't find the com.android.browser all there is is com.android.browser.provider which doesn't have anything else but a cache and fig file. Is the com.android.browser somewhere else? (I'm trying to find a Facebook password I forgot that I had entered in earlier on the stock browser)

Answer (score 0):

The file you are searching does not exist. The stock browser does not use a WebView. Also the databases ate stored inside the `databases` folder.
The only database that should be there (and should not contain any passwords) is the `browser2.db`.